# Latest strongswan update broken in 18.10

Tags: 18.10, ipsec

A lot of `strongswan` files got updated this morning. It breaks strongswan because it can't find `/etc/ipsec.conf`. Sure enough, it's missing. The package file indicates that it's there, but it doesn't get installed.

I went to packages.ubuntu.com and downloaded `strongswan-starter_5.6.3-1ubuntu4.1_amd64.deb` and manually reinstalled it, and IT didn't install /etc/ipsec.conf either!

I manually extracted ipsec.conf from the .deb file, copied it to /etc/ipsec.conf, chmod 644 /etc/ipsec.conf, and made sure it was root:root, then `sudo systemctl restart ipsec`.

`sudo systemctl status ipsec` now shows correctly.

The /etc/ipsec.conf file looks like this...

```
# ipsec.conf - strongSwan IPsec configuration file

# basic configuration

config setup
    # strictcrlpolicy=yes
    # uniqueids = no

# Add connections here.

# Sample VPN connections

#conn sample-self-signed
#      leftsubnet=10.1.0.0/16
#      leftcert=selfCert.der
#      leftsendcert=never
#      right=192.168.0.2
#      rightsubnet=10.2.0.0/16
#      rightcert=peerCert.der
#      auto=start

#conn sample-with-ca-cert
#      leftsubnet=10.1.0.0/16
#      leftcert=myCert.pem
#      right=192.168.0.2
#      rightsubnet=10.2.0.0/16
#      rightid="C=CH, O=Linux strongSwan CN=peer name"
#      auto=start
```

**Update #1:**

Reported at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/strongswan/+bug/1811610

Comment: Sounds a lot like **a bug report** which should be filed on **Launchpad** - not filed here.

Comment: @ThomasWard please give me 10 seconds of instruction on how to do that. I went to launchpad.net and I didn't see an obvious way to report this. I posted this here for other Ubuntu users to find it easily, since this just occurred with the latest updates.

Comment: There's a nice "How do I report a bug" question here already - http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to packages.ubuntu.com and downloaded `strongswan-starter_5.6.3-1ubuntu4.1_amd64.deb` and manually reinstalled it, and IT didn't install /etc/ipsec.conf either!

I manually extracted ipsec.conf from the .deb file, copied it to /etc/ipsec.conf, chmod 644 /etc/ipsec.conf, and made sure it was root:root, then `sudo systemctl restart ipsec`.

`sudo systemctl status ipsec` now shows correctly.

The /etc/ipsec.conf file looks like this...

```
# ipsec.conf - strongSwan IPsec configuration file

# basic configuration

config setup
    # strictcrlpolicy=yes
    # uniqueids = no

# Add connections here.

# Sample VPN connections

#conn sample-self-signed
#      leftsubnet=10.1.0.0/16
#      leftcert=selfCert.der
#      leftsendcert=never
#      right=192.168.0.2
#      rightsubnet=10.2.0.0/16
#      rightcert=peerCert.der
#      auto=start

#conn sample-with-ca-cert
#      leftsubnet=10.1.0.0/16
#      leftcert=myCert.pem
#      right=192.168.0.2
#      rightsubnet=10.2.0.0/16
#      rightid="C=CH, O=Linux strongSwan CN=peer name"
#      auto=start
```